# How do I install TexStudio properly on Mac OS?

Tags: texstudio, installing, macos

I downloaded the `texstudio-3.0.1-osx.dmg` file from https://www.texstudio.org.

Now, when I double click on the dmg file, its supposed to install TexStudio, am I right?

But instead, it just creates this sort of temporary, mountable drive thing on the desktop:

[image]

But I don't think this is proper installation of TexStudio, as I can't find TexStudio in launchpad. Also, even though I can open TexStudio by double clicking on this mountable icon, if I right-click on this icon and click on "eject", TexStudio goes away:

[image]

So, how do I properly install TexStudio such that it persists in the hard disk and also shows up in launchpad as an installed program?

**P.S.:** I have installed MikTex before trying to installing TexStudio, in case it matters.

Comment: MiKTeX on macOS? Use `https://tug.org/mactex` (first remove MiKTeX). Next, double click on the disk image and copyTeXStudio to the Applications folder by dragging the icon.

Comment: @egreg The dmg of MiKTex was only 58 MB, while that of MacTex was 4 GB! So, since my WiFi speed is not great, I didn't have half a day to let MacTex download. Thus, I thought MiKTex should do it. Is it not good enough? I had used it previously, 3-4 years back, and it seemed fine.

Comment: @Kristada673 , the solution you shared doesn't work for me. When I drag the Texstudio application into the Applications folder, it simply creates a shortcut, instead of copying the entire application (like how it takes place for other apps on Mac). Once I eject the mountable drive, the application doesn't work.
Because of this I'm also unable to save settings in Texstudio.

Answer (score 7):

I got the answer, and I'm posting it here in case anyone else faces the same issue in future.

Open Finder and click on Applications:

[image]

Then open the TexStudio mountable drive, and drag the TexStudio icon in it into the Applications opened in the above step.

That's it. TexStudio is now installed, and you can eject the mountable drive thing and also delete the dmg file if you wish.